# How to goto the label in another batch file when the user enter the label

Tags: batch-file

When the user enter the Article ID named "512" or "515" then go to the label in article.bat and then show the message.

**main.bat**

```
@echo off
set /p a="Enter Article ID: "
call article.bat :%a%
```

**article.bat**

```
:512
echo You see the 512
:515
echo You see the 515
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding GOTO %1 to the beginning of Article.bat.

```
GOTO %1

:512
echo You see the 512
:515
echo You see the 515
```

Note that if you enter "512" it will display both messages since it doesn't exit before the next label.

Comment: Sir any idea to goto the particular label?

Comment: @Karthick The GOTO above should do it. But if you want it to terminate after the label, use exit /b before the next label.

`ECHO OFF
GOTO %1

:512
echo You see the 512
exit /b
:515
echo You see the 515
exit /b`

Answer (score 0):

This method have some advantages:

**main.bat**

```
@echo off
set /p a="Enter Article ID: "
call :%a% 2>NUL
if errorlevel 1 (
   echo No such article
) else (
   echo Returned from article.bat
)
goto :EOF

:512
:515
article.bat
```

**article.bat**

```
:512
echo You see the 512
exit /B 0

:515
echo You see the 515
exit /B 0
```